# Unity - OnTriggerEnter & OnTriggerExit strange behavior

Tags: c#, physics, unityscript, collider

I am having a trouble with OnTriggerEnter with a lot of objects.

I have a NavMeshAgent moving randomly throught the scene, then I have a sphere collider inside a children to detect nearby objects. If the object has an allowed tag it adds to the objects_near List.

It starts working right, but when it is working a few secs it starts dropping the objects_near variable to a wrong value, sometimes to 0, then, a few minutes later it drops to 0 permanently.

Is it a Unity bug? Is it my fault because I am using a lot of resources?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCNft.jpg

```
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        string tagname = col.gameObject.tag;

        for (int i = 0; i < tags_allowed.Length; i++)
        {
            if (tags_allowed[i] == tagname)
            {
                objects_near.Add(col.gameObject);
            }
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
    {
        string tagname = col.gameObject.tag;

        for (int i = 0; i < tags_allowed.Length; i++)
        {
            if (tags_allowed[i] == tagname)
            {
                objects_near.Remove(col.gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure OnTriggerEnter() detects more than one object everytime it is called;

Comment: As an aside, generally you'll want to compare tags using the `CompareTag` method, not `==`. This saves some extra marshalling with each comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EDITED:

**Found a solution not using triggers**.

I have removed Triggers functions and changed the functionality.

First I check all the GameObjects in the scene with the allowed tags. (tags_allowed is a string array).

Then I check the distance from the IA (NavMeshAgent) to each object in the scene with an allowd tag.

If the GameObject detected is near than a distance I add it to the objects_near List. And if it is not, I remove it.

#### void Update()

```
objects_near_tmp = null;
for (int i = 0; i < tags_allowed.Length; i ++)
{
    objects_near_tmp = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(tags_allowed[i]);
    for (int j = 0; j < objects_near_tmp.Length; j++)
    {
        float dist = Vector3.Distance(objects_near_tmp[j].transform.position, transform.position);
        if (dist < 20f)
        {
            bool add_object_near = true;
            if (objects_near.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < objects_near.Count; k++)
                {
                    if (objects_near[k] == objects_near_tmp[j])
                    {
                        add_object_near = false;
                    }
                }

                if (add_object_near == true)
                {
                    objects_near.Add(objects_near_tmp[j]);
                }
            }   
            else
            {
                objects_near.Add(objects_near_tmp[j]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            objects_near.Remove(objects_near_tmp[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, you could expand this answer to better address the problem you found a solution for. This way other users may benefit from this question in the future. Also, you may set this answer as a correct answer, and thus close the question.